# How to escape slash '\' in regex?

Tags: javascript, escaping, slash

I need to escape `\` in this regax `/(\W)***C6/add6***\s/`.

I'm using this function to find chord in song and replace to something else.

How can I escape slash ?

Comment: Read the basic intro to regexp at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions. Near the top of the page, you will see *A backslash that precedes a special character indicates that the next character is not special and should be interpreted literally*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
/(\W)*\*\*C6\/add6*\*\*\s/
```

Answer (score 2):

To escape character add `\`.

Like this: `/(\W)C6\\add6\s/`.